# Provide information to the customer immediately - rather than reload the page

Tags: php, html, email, mysqli

I would like to give our customer beskede to have been written a beskede to person and he will be contacted as soon as possible, but at present for the page to reload. So it has to send the same time provide some information about it is sent.

My mind is to use something JavaScript or jQuery or AJAX, but this area I don't know so well :)

```
<div class="kontakt_box">
        <h3>Kontakt Mads Ørnfeldt Andersen</h3>
        <p>Kom i kontakt med Mads Ørnfeldt Andersen</p>
            <?php
                $email_afsender = $mebe->email_afsender();
            ?>
            <form action="#" method="post" name="kontakt_box">
                <label>Navn<br /><input type="text" name="navn" required title="Angive et Navn" class="new" placeholder="Navn"></label><br />
                <label>Efternavn<br /><input type="text" required title="Angive et efternavn" name="efternavn" class="new" placeholder="Efternavn"></label><br />
                <label>Email<br /><input type="email" required title="Angive en email!" name="email" class="new" placeholder="Email"></label><br />
                <label>Tekst<br /><textarea name="tekst" cols="35" rows="10" class="new"  required title="Skrive noget indhold i email!!" placeholder="Tekst til email"></textarea></label><br />
                <label><input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" class="new"></label>
            </form>
    </div>
```

Here is my code code:

```
function email_afsender()
{
    if(isset($_POST["send"]))
    {
        $fra = $_POST["navn"] . " " . $_POST["efternavn"] . "<" . $_POST["email"] . ">";
        $til = "hello@world.dk";
        $emne = "Kontakt blabla.dk - " . $_POST["navn"] . " " . $_POST["efternavn"];
        $besked = $_POST["tekst"];

        //headers

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: " . $fra . "\r\n";

        mail($til, $emne, $besked, $headers);

        ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
            window.location.href = "/kontakt/";  
        </script> 
        <?php

    }
}
```

**What my problem is:**

I would like to send the email but also show a message to the user that the email has been sent below the form: "Thank you we look at your case as soon as possible."

You can see my problem [here](http://www.absb.dk/kontakt/)

*Sorry my English is bad but I'm dyslexic and have difficulty it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think your problem is not beeing dyslexic, but using google translate.**

Instead of using:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
        window.location.href = "/kontakt/";  
    </script>
```

You should do http redirect:

```
header('Location: ' . $TargetPage);
```

Comment: it help me a lot. now I just want it to provide a beskede to the user that it has been sent now!

Comment: Its better to try your own, even basic english than using translate.

To provide a message that the mail was sent - set variable $MessageSent = true; and in template show some text above the form if($MessageSent)

Comment: @peku33: a `Location` header should always be followed by `exit()` otherwise it will carry on executing the script until the server realises the client has disconnected.

Comment: it is not in a way best that I make a "$ _SESSION [" email_sendt "] = true" so that after making an if where it asks you to "$ _SESSION [" email_sendt "] is true again." so that after the message is displayed.

Comment: its work!.. :) I make a new question since I have a new problem